# Put trace id for each message in kafka listener

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-bean

How can i use `KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` to add trace id for each message coming to the consumer?
I want to avoid using `ThreadContext.put()` in each of the listeners. What's the best practice that is followed for this purpose? Is there any better way of doing it without using `KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.
Also I cannot use Sleuth because its creating some issue with my application. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the tracing library ( including [Spring Cloud Sleuth](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-sleuth) which in turn internally uses [Brave](https://github.com/openzipkin/brave) as tracing library) generally utilize Threadlocal to store the tracing. So it would be simpler to use Threadlocal if what you want is just a tracing id. Of course in that case you would need to propagate the tracing id yourself. You can use [Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) to write and apply the threadlocal tracing id logic generation/cleanup in an non-invasive way.  Another approach is to integrate the Brave library yourself as detailed here in their supported instrumentation options for Kafka clients [here](https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/blob/master/instrumentation/kafka-clients/README.md).